# Prevent washer from leaving brown splotchy stains on clothes

Tags: repair, washing-machine, stain

Our clothes will periodically come out of our washing machine with brown splotchy stains. I suspect it's either rust or oil/grease getting into the drum. How can I  diagnose what it is exactly, and prevent it from happening?

I have wiped down the top of the drum, both on the inside and above the drum where it meets the metal chassis of the washer.

I also removed and cleaned the fabric softener container, and removed the agitator and cleaned the inside and below the agitator (there was a ton of built up dirt). After removing the agitator, I cleaned that in the sink with soap, water, and baking soda. I cleaned by filling the drum with hot water (as if about to start a cycle), and then adding a cup of bleach and cup of baking soda, while leaving the door open. After letting soak for an hour, I scrubbed the place where the agitator attaches to the bottom of the drum and wiped down all the loose dirt.

I also stumbled upon an errant bobby pin, which I suspect has been the real culprit here. Will answer this question if the splotches disappear. Thanks to @ noybman for all the help.

Comment: could also be rust. How old is the unit? Is it front loading or top? Do you have well water or municipality water? Does your clean toilet water ever appear unclear?

Comment: @noybman yeah I mentioned in my question that it may be rust. I don't know how old the unit it, I'm in a rental. It's top loading using municipality water, which is always clear and colorless

Comment: Do other people use the unit as well? When the unit is empty, does the drum or agitator if it has one seem very lose? Do you use liquid or powder detergent? (front loader or top?)

Comment: @noybman no other people using it. Not sure how to tell if the drum is loose. It's moveable but feels like that's normal. Agitator doesn't seem loose. We use liquid detergent that's clear.

Comment: Take a damp thick rag, and run it alongside the inner upper part of the drum and the metal chassis above the drum. You should also feel a plastic/rubber assembly there where the rinse water comes from. Look to see if you get debris or rust on it from that *(be careful in case it is sharp). Also, look for a label on the unit, The model # and date of manufacture should be on it.

Comment: @noybmanThanks for your help, sorry for the delay in response. I wiped down the top of the drum, on the inside and around the metal chassis above. There was some dirt, but it wasn't the rusty brown color of what had been staining our clothes.

Comment: Iron/rust coming in with the water. Either the supply or possibly your own pipes ( if steel , if galvanizing is damaged). There is water softener type equipment sold for this, I am not sure it works , ( I think they use permanganate to recharge .)

Comment: @blacksmith37I don't think it's from the water--see my first comment--my water is always clear and colorless when it fills the drum.

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily notice it in the water itself but it could still be there. Take the fill tube off the back of the washer and look at the inlet, if it is discolored, then its likely supply end, if it isn't, its got to be something in the washer most likely from the fill areas. The other possibility is the drum itself if the unit recirculates water. In either case, best option is a new unit

Comment: @isherwood this question was about "maintenance, and repair of major appliances" since it was unclear what the cause of the problem was. Not sure why it's being closed 5 years later

Comment: I'm not sure cleaning qualifies as maintenance. That's the distinction. It was a matter of debris in the machine, not worn parts, etc.

Comment: @isherwood But at the time the question was asked, it wasn't clear what the answer was, or what category the answer would fall into. Also machines malfunctioning due to debris is also part of maintenance and repair, no? Obviously it's not a huge deal to close this one question, I'm just confused in that it seems like depending on the answer, the question could be off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*An answer, buried in the question text by the OP 5 years ago:*

> I also stumbled upon an errant bobby pin, which I suspect has been the real culprit here

Comment: If someone would up vote this _community wiki_ answer, this will stop getting the community bump! (No, I'm not pandering for points, that's why I made it CW.)

Comment: The question should've been closed. It's about appliance usage.

Answer (score 2):

Well the first need is to identify the stain.  I was a dry cleaner for 40 years.  Dry Cleaners have a "rust-go" or "erusticator" bottle.  One drop on a brown stain will instantly disappear that little circle of stain if it is rust.  It will not work on any brown stain except rust!

A source of rust in laundry comes from invisible iron in the water.  Chlorine bleach will precipitate it out as rust.  Many people have made worse stains by attempting to get brown stains out with bleach in the next wash....

RazeR

Comment: While this may get the stain out of the clothes and is valuable info, the OP asked what he can do to prevent the stains from happening in the first place. Please feel free to [edit] in any tips you may have on that.

Comment: Well preventing the stains involves knowing first what they are!  If they are in fact rust it will not likely be from the machine.  If it is from iron in the water, only limited prevention is possible.  Number one, don't use chlorine and number two, install a softener with filtering media to not only soften hard water but also remove iron.  Not a cheap or easy solution, unfortunately, and another washer will have the same problem.....the water can be tested for iron content: a city 30 miles from mine had high iron and customers came from there to wash in my laundromat to escape the high iron.

Comment: Try removing the agitator and look at the transmission seals, I have seen failing washing machine transmissions periodically put grease in the wash water. Water flows past the seal into the transmission pushing transmission fluid out. If this is true you need to replace the transmission and generally it is more cost effective to replace the washer. Check with your neighbors and see if any of them are having this problem to rule out the water source.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the oxyclean powder? I would get these brownish spots randomly when trying to get my whites extra bright by using oxy powder and bleach. I'm not 100% positive that this is what was doing it but I stopped mixing the two and I stopped getting those spots.(the bleach would turn a dark burnt orange color when I would pour it into the water cantainibg the oxy, but only briefly)